# Merging 2 different table into 1 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 different excel file that I need to merge into one table in MySQL. I have exported both file in CSV and imported into 2 different table into MySQL.

The first table (Central) has :

> `id, name, surname, address, zip, filedA, fieldB, fieldC, fieldD`

The second table (Magazine) has :

> id (different than the "Central" one), name, surname, address, zip,
>   fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ

The goal is to have a table with :

> id, name, surname, address, zip, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, fieldD,
>   fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ

The main problem is that in table "`Central`" I have several rows (1000) and those are the master. In table "Magazine" I have another set of rows (also 1000) but some exist in "Central" some does not.

What I want to do, is a loop that can or create another table or update the "Central" one with the "`Magazine`" one, updating rows that exist in both table and inserting new rows for the one that just exist in the "Magazine" one.

PK are not the same but we can make the assumption that the pair name, surname are enough to match rows in both table.

Thanks

Comment: How do you define: `rows that exist in both tables`?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius Read the last line of the question: name and surname identify the duplicates

Comment: @Barmar then, first of all, the database structure is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the new table, define `name, surname` as a unique key so we can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to detect matches.

```
CREATE TABLE newtable ( /* field definitions */,
  UNIQUE INDEX (name, surname) );
```

Then load the data from `Central` first:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (id, name, surname, address, zip, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, fieldD)
SELECT id, name, surname, address, zip, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, fieldD
FROM Central;
```

Now merge in the data from `Magazine`, updating matching rows with the new fields.

```
INSERT INTO newtable (id, name, surname, address, zip, fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ)
SELECT id, name, surname, address, zip, fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ
FROM Magazine
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = VALUES(id), address = VALUES(address),
                        zip = VALUES(zip), fieldX = VALUES(fieldX),
                        fieldY = VALUES(fieldY), fieldZ = VALUES(fieldZ);
```

There's probably a way to do it all in one `INSERT`, but since MySQL doesn't have `CROSS JOIN` it will be a PITA to code.

Comment: Hi Barmar,Many thanks for the help that was great and worked just fine (just had to add a S to VALUE).

Answer (score 0):

```
create table new_table as select * from (   
 SELECT a.id, a.name, a.surname, a.address, a.zip, a.filedA, a.fieldB, a.fieldC, a.fieldD, b.fieldX, b.fieldY, b.fieldZ FROM Central a
    LEFT JOIN Magazine b ON (a.name = b.name and a.surname = b.surname)
    UNION
    SELECT b.id, b.name, b.surname, b.address, b.zip, a.filedA, a.fieldB, a.fieldC, a.fieldD, b.fieldX, b.fieldY, b.fieldZ FROM Central a
    RIGHT JOIN Magazine b ON (a.name = b.name and a.surname = b.surname) ) temp
```

Comment: Will this method ensure that rows from Magazine take precedence when there are duplicate names? Won't you end up with multiple rows, because the `id` fields are different?